# Why Laravel updates a var after model update

Tags: laravel

I try to fetch the previous and the new assignee on an issue. I like do send a notification to both, the old and the new assignee.

When I do like the following code, the `$oldIssue` is also updated:

```
    public function update(Request $request, Issue $issue)
    {

        $oldIssue = $issue;

        $issue->update($request->all());

        return response()->json([
            $oldIssue->assignee_id, $issue->assignee_id
        ]);
    }
//[2, 2]
```

(Thee return is only to test)

If I take the id in the var, it works:

```
    public function update(Request $request, Issue $issue)
    {

        $oldIssue = $issue->assignee_id;

        $issue->update($request->all());

        return response()->json([
            $oldIssue, $issue->assignee_id
        ]);
    }
// [2, 3]
```

Why it doesn't work in the first case? Why the `$oldIssue` var is also updated?

Answer (score 0):

When you do that `$oldIssue = $issue;` it becomes the reference to the actual variable.

Can you update this line it will fix your bug.

```
$oldIssue = clone $issue;
```